# Is it possible to send an email through PHPMailer in XML format?

Tags: xml, phpmailer

Basically exactly what the title suggest: is it possible to send the body of an email (not as an attachment) as XML through PHP mailer.

The formatting seems to continually be an issue and I am just wondering if this is even possible?

Comment: email doesn't care what's in the body of the email. that's not its job - it just delivers an envelope, basically. probably your mail client is trying to RENDER the xml, e.g. it's not being treated as plain-text email.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I just realized that, and this goes for anyone:

When trying to send a plain-text email, as simple as it is, make sure AltBody isn't there and obviously make sure isHTML is false.

Again, I don't know why my brain struggled with this, but thanks Marc.