# how to send a XML message with PHP mailer

Tags: xml, phpmailer

I am struggling with the same problem as in [Is it possible to send an email through PHPMailer in XML format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35991241/6062044) but that solution doesnt solve my problem.

Using the PHPMailer I want to send XML messages. I have removed the $mail->AltBody. I use: $mail->isHTML(false); $mail->MsgHTML($body);

THe result is that the messagebody has two parts: 1: content-type:text/plain 2: content-type:text/html

my thunderbird Email client shows only the plain text but when looking at the source both texts are there. The text/plain contains the translated XML (I don't want that).

Is it correct to put XML content in a content-type : text/html of does a content-type text/xml exists?

Can I prevent the text/plain to be translated or to be populated at all?

Any directions are welcome.

Robbert.

Answer (score 0):

It really helps to [read the docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_msgHTML), or failing that, the code. Don't call random functions and expect them to magically know what you want.

To set raw message format, set `ContentType` to the MIME type you want (`texe/xml`) and put the content into `Body`. That's all you need to do.

Comment: I had read the doc's you referred to but don't understand enough what is happening. That's why I try to get the understanding using examples I can find. I've added a custum header with "content-type:text/xml" and tried "content-type:application/xml".  The I get an Error from a SPAM filter. I have read that some mail backends don't trust messages with  "X-mailer: PHP mailer"

Comment: I had read the doc's you referred to but don't understand enough what is happening. That's why I try to get the understanding using examples I can find. I've added a custum header with "content-type:text/xml" and tried "content-type:application/xml".  The I get an Error from a SPAM filter. "SMTP Error: Data not accepted. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Data not accepted. SMTP server error: Message refused by spam filter".
 I have read that some mail backends don't trust messages with  "X-mailer: PHP mailer.." maybe the combination with the  XML header?